# Why does FindMinimum return 'The function value Null is not a real number'?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am working with the following function

```
Catch[Do[a = 2^(m*(1 - c)) - 2.718/((m^.5)*2*3.14*c^(c*m + .5) *(1 - c)^((1 - c)*m+ .5)); 
If[a <= 0, Throw[m/(m (1 - c) + 1)]], {c, 0.006, 1, 0.001}]]
```

and would like to find its minimum between `m=4` and `m=2,500`.

However, if I try writing

```
FindMinimum[ Catch[Do[a = 2^(m*(1 - c)) - 2.718/((m^.5)*2*3.14*c^(c*m + .5) *(1 - c)^((1 - c)*m + .5));
If[a <= 0, Throw[m/(m (1 - c) + 1)]], {c, 0.006, 1, 0.001}]], {m, 4, 2500}]
```

it returns

> "FindMinimum::nrnum: The function value Null is not a real number at \
>   {m} = {4.}. >>"

I'm not sure why this is, as the function is equal to 1.11235 at m=4, with no imaginary part.

How can I get the `FindMinimum` function to work?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Ok, will do! Thanks Lou

Comment: First, your "function" does not execute properly, when I enter the `Catch[ ... ]` as above, there are errors, so of course you cannot do anything with it (like find it's minimum).

Comment: You're right, sorry. It works now (if you specify a value for m)

Comment: Are you trying to enforce the condition that `a` is zero with your `Do` loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your function:

```
f[m_] := Catch[
  Do[a = 2^(m*(1 - c)) - 
     2.718/((m^.5)*2*3.14*c^(c*m + .5)*(1 - c)^((1 - c)*m + .5));
   If[a <= 0, Throw[m/(m (1 - c) + 1)]], {c, 0.006, 1, 0.001}]]
```

and here is a plot of this over 4 to 2500

```
Plot[f[m], {m, 4, 2500}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Pretty clearly the min is at f[4].

Comment: Yes, it is. However, as I'm working with many functions of this type it would be very nice to be able to use a Mathematica function to find their minimum rather than having to plot them all.

This is also part of me trying to get to grips with Mathematica.

Any idea why 

FindMinimum[ Catch[Do[a = 2^(m*(1 - c)) - 2.718/((m^.5)*2*3.14*c^(c*m + .5) *(1 - c)^((1 - c)*m + .5));
If[a <= 0, Throw[m/(m (1 - c) + 1)]], {c, 0.006, 1, 0.001}]], {m, 4, 2500}]

doesn't work?

Comment: I believe you can't use FindMinimum on functions created from iterations like Do... the functions need to be differentiable (at least for most of the minimization methods) and so this kind of programming construct is unlikely to work.

Comment: Ah ok, I'll have to justify my answers graphically then. Thanks!

Comment: Try plotting from 1 to 4.  You'll see that 4 is **not** the minimum.

Comment: @2012rcampion -- the OP explicitly asked for the min between m=4 and m=2500. m=4 does indeed give the min in this range.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps better:

```
NMinimize[{m/(m (1 - c) + 1), 
  2^(m*(1 - c)) - 2.718/((m^.5)*2*3.14*c^(c*m + .5)*(1 - c)^((1 - c)*m + .5)) <= 0 &&    
  0.006 <= c <= 1 && 
   4 <= m <= 2500}, {m, c}, MaxIterations -> 300]

(* {1.11184, {m -> 4., c -> 0.350592}} *)
```

Comment: can't get that to work...how did you run it?

Comment: @Lupacante It works as is here. Try it after starting a fresh Mathematica session

Comment: @belisarius - very nice! I couldn't see how to make the Catch-Do-Throw into a function... I think you've got it!

Comment: @bills I hate those `Do[]`s :)

Comment: Doesn't work for me...do you run the whole thing, including the commented out part? Do I need to add anything at the beginning?

Comment: @Lupacante What Mathematica version are you using?

Comment: @Lupacante This works OK on V9 and V10. Confirmed.

Comment: version 6...that might be why

Comment: @Lupacante V6 was released in 2007. V10 is the current version. Sorry, I don't have v6 available anymore. But try to upgrade as a lot of things have improved since 2007 :)